# Control animation and execute script when animation ends

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project is a military fps and i'm having some problems with animations.

I have 3 different weapons, 1 animator controller for each one and every weapon has a "enter" and "leave" animation. Like CS, COD, etc...

I need to know when my "leave" animation ends to disable the gameobject, enable the other one and play the "enter" animation.

I tryed to do this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/362629/how-can-i-check-if-an-animation-is-being-played-or.html but without sucess.

I'll leave here a print of the animator controller, the hierarchy and the script, if u need more details, just need to say.

[image]

Animator controller of the weapon number 1

All transitions to "Sair" (leave animation) have a trigger (AK47_sair) and the transition to "Extit" state have a trigger ("AK47_SairControlador")

On my code, when i press 2 (change to weapon number 2) i want to do the transition.

[image]

This is the hierarchy, my script is attached to "Jogador".

With my actual code, it disable tha AK47 gameobject when the leave animation still playing.

```
    using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class FirstPerson : MonoBehaviour {

     public float speed;
     public float normalSpeed = 5.0f;
     public float slowSpeed = 2.5f;
     public float crchSpeed = 2.5f;

     private Transform tr;
     private float dist; // distance to ground


     public float mouseSensitivity = 5.0f;
     public float verticalRotation = 0.0f;
     public float updownRange = 60.0f;
     private float verticalSpeed = 0.0f;
     public float jumpSpeed = 5.0f;

     CharacterController player;

     private GameObject AK47;
     private GameObject Faca;

     public float shootingRate = 0.15f;
     public float shootCooldown;

     private bool agachado = false;
     public float camOriginalPositionY;
     public float camCrouchPositionY;

     private Animator controladorAnimacaoAK;
     private Animator controladorAnimacaoFaca;


     public CapsuleCollider playerCollider;
     public Camera CameraPrincipal;

     public int ArmaSelecionada;
     public int UltimaArma;



     void Start () {
         player = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
         shootCooldown = 0;
         controladorAnimacaoAK = player.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
         playerCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ();
         CameraPrincipal = Camera.main;
         ArmaSelecionada = 1;
         AK47 = CameraPrincipal.transform.FindChild ("ak47_final_animado").gameObject;
     }



     void Update () {

         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Alpha2) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad2)) {
             UltimaArma = ArmaSelecionada;
             ArmaSelecionada = 2;

             if(UltimaArma == 1) {
                 controladorAnimacaoAK.SetTrigger("AK47_Sair");
     controladorAnimacaoAK.SetTrigger("AK47_SairControlador");
                 AK47.SetActive (false);


             }

         }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Alpha1)) {
             UltimaArma = ArmaSelecionada;
             ArmaSelecionada = 1;
         //    controladorAnimacaoAK.SetTrigger ("AK47_Entrar");
         }

         if (ArmaSelecionada == 1) {
             // diz ao controlador da anim se o player esta a movimentar-se ou nao
             controladorAnimacaoAK.SetFloat ("AK47_Deslocacao", player.velocity.magnitude);
             //Debug.Log (player.velocity.magnitude);

             // dispatar tiros
             PlayerShoot PlayerShootScript = player.GetComponent<PlayerShoot> ();

             if (shootCooldown > 0) {
                 shootCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
             }


             if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) {
                 if (shootCooldown <= 0) {
                     shootCooldown = shootingRate;
                     PlayerShootScript.FireShoot ();
                     // animaçao
                     controladorAnimacaoAK.SetBool ("AK47_Disparar", true);
                 }
             } else {

                 // animaçao
                 controladorAnimacaoAK.SetBool ("AK47_Disparar", false);
             }

             if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R)) {
                 controladorAnimacaoAK.SetTrigger ("AK47_rec");
             } 
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity 5 you've got this new thing which is Animation State Machine Behavior : [State Machine Behaviours](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours)

You can use it to specify behavior when the Animation Controller enters or leave specific states.

For exemple here I've got my door which have an Open and Close state, and let's say that I want to play a sound when the door is opening.

[image: Opening animation]

Here I clicked Opening, then Add Behaviour and set a random name for the test (Behavior Test in my case)

Then I just need to implement the function *void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)* to play a sound at the first frame the animation is running.

```
[SerializeField]
AudioClip open_sound;

override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    animator.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = open_sound;
    animator.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

In your case, you would want to implement a behavior in the state *Disparar* which implements the function *OnStateExit([...])* and handle the weapon change.

To go a bit further I don't think you *should* handle the weapon change directly in the animation state, but maybe your script could send an event catched by a Game Controller that will actually handle the change of weapon.

Comment: Thanks you, with some adjustments this solved my problem!